# Why is validator inactive on Stellarbeat despite logs showing validation activity?

Tags: stellar-core, validators

I am trying to run a validator, and have configured it accordingly.
I am running version 12.4 on an Ubuntu machine, which I installed using the stellar-core-postgres packages.

According to `stellar-core http-command info` the node's state is "synced".

I have been observing what seems to be successful validation activity, however, my node is not recognised on Stellarbeat as  a validator or even an active node.

Here is some of my config file. What am I doing wrong?

```
NODE_SEED=Sxxxxx
NODE_IS_VALIDATOR=true
NODE_HOME_DOMAIN="mydomain.de"
FAILURE_SAFETY=1
UNSAFE_QUORUM=false
CATCHUP_COMPLETE=false
CATCHUP_RECENT=1024
[[HOME_DOMAINS]]
HOME_DOMAIN="stellar.org"
QUALITY="HIGH"
[[HOME_DOMAINS]]
HOME_DOMAIN="lobstr.co"
QUALITY="HIGH"
[[HOME_DOMAINS]]
HOME_DOMAIN="coinqvest.com"
QUALITY="HIGH"
[[HOME_DOMAINS]]
HOME_DOMAIN="wirexapp.com"
QUALITY="MEDIUM"
[[HOME_DOMAINS]]
HOME_DOMAIN="stellar.blockdaemon.com"
QUALITY="MEDIUM"
[[HOME_DOMAINS]]
HOME_DOMAIN="mydomain.de"
QUALITY="LOW"
[[VALIDATORS]]
NAME="SDF validator 1"
HOME_DOMAIN="stellar.org"
PUBLIC_KEY="GCGB2S2KGYARPVIA37HYZXVRM2YZUEXA6S33ZU5BUDC6THSB62LZSTYH"
ADDRESS="core-live-a.stellar.org"
HISTORY="curl -sf http://history.stellar.org/prd/core-live/core_live_001/{0} -o {1}"
[[VALIDATORS]]
NAME="SDF validator 2"
HOME_DOMAIN="stellar.org"
PUBLIC_KEY="GCM6QMP3DLRPTAZW2UZPCPX2LF3SXWXKPMP3GKFZBDSF3QZGV2G5QSTK"
ADDRESS="core-live-b.stellar.org"
HISTORY="curl -sf http://history.stellar.org/prd/core-live/core_live_002/{0} -o {1}"
[[VALIDATORS]]
NAME="SDF validator 3"
HOME_DOMAIN="stellar.org"
PUBLIC_KEY="GABMKJM6I25XI4K7U6XWMULOUQIQ27BCTMLS6BYYSOWKTBUXVRJSXHYQ"
ADDRESS="core-live-c.stellar.org"
HISTORY="curl -sf http://history.stellar.org/prd/core-live/core_live_003/{0} -o {1}"
[[VALIDATORS]]
NAME="LOBSTR (North America)"
HOME_DOMAIN="lobstr.co"
PUBLIC_KEY="GD5QWEVV4GZZTQP46BRXV5CUMMMLP4JTGFD7FWYJJWRL54CELY6JGQ63"
ADDRESS="v3.stellar.lobstr.co:11625"
HISTORY="curl -sf https://stellar-archive-3-lobstr.s3.amazonaws.com/{0} -o {1}"
[[VALIDATORS]]
NAME="LOBSTR (Asia)"
HOME_DOMAIN="lobstr.co"
PUBLIC_KEY="GA7TEPCBDQKI7JQLQ34ZURRMK44DVYCIGVXQQWNSWAEQR6KB4FMCBT7J"
ADDRESS="v4.stellar.lobstr.co:11625"
HISTORY="curl -sf https://stellar-archive-4-lobstr.s3.amazonaws.com/{0} -o {1}"
```

Below is a recent output of my log file.

```
2020-03-07T17:42:33.996 GBIVB [Ledger INFO] Got consensus: [seq=28569269, prev=7c74bb, txs=107, ops=180, sv: [ txH: edc6c0, ct: 1583602953, upgrades: [ ] ]]
2020-03-07T17:42:34.053 GBIVB [Tx INFO] applying ledger 28569269 (txs:107, ops:180)
2020-03-07T17:42:34.324 GBIVB [Ledger INFO] Closed ledger: [seq=28569269, hash=8f8fd1]
2020-03-07T17:42:39.476 GBIVB [Herder INFO] Quorum information for 28569268 : {"agree":12,"delayed":0,"disagree":0,"fail_at":3,"hash":"c98445","ledger":28569268,"missing":0,"phase":"EXTERNALIZE","validated":true}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: How do you even find the list of validators?  Stellar captive core docs only list testnet config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this and sharing in case anyone runs in to the same problem:

My node was validating the ledgers as the logs were showing, HOWEVER, the port I was using was closed. Hence, it was not reachable from outside. A simple nmap scan will show you if your node is reachable on the given port or not.